# Non SPA frontend - Best practices for ~immediately interactive JS elements

Tags: javascript

I am currently planning a revamp of a client's website, it's a consumer facing ecommerce site (non-SPA), one area of focus is client side performance.

One of the hot areas of the site is the menu navigiation with slide down second levels etc.., which is in the top fold, and we want this is be working almost immediately, even if the users connection is slow. It is not within reach to do this with CSS just yet, due to browsers we are targetting and the scope of this overhaul - although it is noted this would be a target for the next year.

Most blogs are still pushing idea of waiting for onReady (or a non jQuery equivalent) before doing stuff with the DOM, I'm of the opinion this is too late, especially on mobile, and we do care about first non-cached load.

What are good strategies and patterns for loading Javascript so that certain elements are functioning as quick as possible?

I have so far considered a similar pattern to GTM datalayer.push and the old GA _gaq.push

```
<script src="/js/menu.js" defer="true" />
<body>
 <div id="menu" data-comment="obviously massively simplified here">
     <a onclick="function(e) { window.actionQueue.push(e) }; return false">a link</a>
```

Doesn't block the page from loading, kicks off loading of menu as soon as possible (which might finish before domReady), menu.js empties actionQueue and overwrites push for future firing... next page request should have cached menu.js and so it pretty much should work immediately

Or perhaps capture click at body level to remove the inline js

```
<script>
 window.actionQueue = [];
 window.document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(e.target.className.includes("menu-item")) {
      window.actionQueue.push(e)
      return false;
    }
 });
</script>
<script src="/js/menu.js" defer="true" />
<body>

  <div id="menu" data-comment="obviously massively simplified here">
     <a class='menu-link">a link</a>
```

What are issues with this approach? Is there anything better?

Comment: How much JS is there…? If it can basically be inlined into the onclick attributes, or put immediately after in a synchronously executing `<script>` element, why not just do that?

Comment: Let's say it will be ~10kb for the menu due to different functionality and style for mobile, in this year optimization it not within scope to change the apperance significantly, it's currently over 50kb due to jquery.mmenu (ripping that out). However we have other elements on the page too that require JS initialization so the pattern would be applied there too, I fear we could end up with too much inlined if we just put sync <script> after each initialization point losing the benefit of js caching on next page load.

Comment: Fair enough. I think your approaches are pretty good then.